# Could not initialize class com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter. DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28P01, Error Code = 0

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

Can I get assistance with the error codes coming from eclipse when I try to deploy enterprise application on websphere. I followed craig st jean, I also face another problem with configuration i.e websphere data sources using postgresql. i am using a windows machine, 64bit arch. the error codes are the topic of this question. i hope this question can be seen as relevant, since not much solutions exist for the first issue concerning com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter, thus if one doesn't overcome the first, how can one press on and attempt to solve the second. thanks.

Webspere logs

```
The test connection operation failed for data source AppDb on server server1 at node Lenovo-PCNode01 with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "listmanagerremote" DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28P01, Error Code = 0. View JVM logs for further details.
```

I have fixed the issues with deployment in the eclipse neon IDE. I think it is either as a result of the installation of the IBM WebSphere Application Server Traditional v8.0x Developer tools for Neon, and IBM jre.

Eclipse console final message

```
00000063 CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=ListManager in BLA WebSphere:blaname=ListManager started.
```

Comment: @aguibert i edited the question to include the error message. since it is my first time with websphere, so i am studying the server.xml to be able to put up the right configuration. will appreciate some guidance. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgre documents the 28P01 SQL State as an invalid password:

"28P01  INVALID PASSWORD    invalid_password"

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Check your data source configuration to ensure that you have specified the correct password, or if using an authentication alias for your data source, confirm that the authentication data configuration contains the correct password, and that you have configured the data source and/or resource reference to use that authentication data.